# Running powershell script from other powershell synchronically

Tags: .net, powershell, asynchronous

I have 2 powershell scripts (A.ps1 and B.ps1).

I want to call script B.ps1 from script A.ps1, but let A.ps1 continue with it execution after calling B.ps1 and not to wait for B.ps1 to finish its execution (i.e. running B.ps1 in an async way).

How can that be achieved? 
I tried:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\scripts\B.ps1'"
```

but that causes script A to wait until script B is done.

I also tried:

```
Start-Process 'C:\scripts\B.ps1'
```

But for some reason this cmdlet doesn't work on my machine at all (it actually opens up the "How do you want to open this file?" window and no matter what I choose it just keep showing this window)

I'm using powershell version 5.1

Thanks,

Noam

Comment: Maybe using `Start-Job` : `Start-Job -FilePath "c:\scripts\B.ps1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are scripts examples :

I have set sleep timers to show you that even if **B.ps1** starts notepad and wait 5 seconds after, **A.ps1** still continues to display second by second timer and does not wait for **B.ps1** to be finished.

**A.ps1 :** (displays a timer second by second until 10)

```
1..10 | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    Write-Host $_
    if($_ -eq 3){
        Start-Job -FilePath .\B.ps1
    }
}
```

**B.ps1 :** (starts a notepad)

```
Start-Process notepad
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```

Refer to Example 4 in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Thanks for answering, it seems like it should work but it doesn't, I can see that after calling `start-job` , A.ps1 keeps with it execution (as it should) but in task manager after the start-job cmdlet I can see powershell.exe process open and closed 3 seconds later while it execution should be much longer (about 2 minutes), how can I debug this to see why is this happening?

Comment: Start B.ps1 only and not in a job and see what happens. I don't know what you've done in A.ps1 and B.ps1. However you can upvote and mark my answer as accepted as now you can start asynchronously your 2 scripts. If you have another problem, you should start another question.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your Script:

```
$Job = Start-Job -FilePath 'C:\Path\To\Script.ps1';
#Script continues here
```

Then, if the script has output, at end of script:

```
$Output = Wait-Job $Job | Receive-Job;
Remove-Job $Job;
# Do whatever with $Output
```

If the script didn't have output:

```
Wait-Job $Job | Remove-Job;
```

Obviously, there's no error checking or correction here at all.  Jobs can be in a failed state or return errors, and ideally you'll want to handle that.  You can learn more at `Get-Help about_Jobs`, `Get-Help about_Job_Details`, and the `Get-Help` entries for the individual commands.